# Android Studio 1.3 Beta 1 bug when trying to create Google Cloud Module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, module

I was using Android Studio 1.3 from Canary channel and it was working totally find until I tried to create Google Cloud Module. Regardless of which type and client app the Android Studio just hangs. Here is the error code from Terminal:

> [ 121126]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Read access is
>   allowed from event dispatch thread or inside read-action only (see
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.Application.runReadAction()) Details:
>   Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6,4,main]
>   314219946 ; dispatch thread: false; isDispatchThread(): false
>   SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0 1.3#AI-141.2017176,
>   eap:true,6,main] 686742728  java.lang.Throwable   at
>   com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:126)     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.assertReadAccessAllowed(ApplicationImpl.java:976)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleManagerImpl.findModuleByName(ModuleManagerImpl.java:525)
>     at
>   com.google.gct.idea.appengine.wizard.CloudModuleUtils.createModule(CloudModuleUtils.java:112)
>     at
>   com.google.gct.idea.appengine.wizard.NewCloudModuleDynamicWizardPath.performFinishingActions(NewCloudModuleDynamicWizardPath.java:91)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.doFinish(DynamicWizard.java:648)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard$1.run(DynamicWizard.java:428)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:237)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:367)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:617)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
>   [ 121131]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Android Studio
>   AI-141.2017176  Build #AI-141.2017176  [ 121131]  ERROR -
>   plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_40  [ 121131]  ERROR -
>   plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   [ 121131]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Oracle
>   Corporation  [ 121131]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS:
>   Linux  [ 121134]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last
>   Action: NewModuleInGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by removing Android Studio 1.3 and make clean install of 1.2.2 from stable channel. But maybe there is a solution to fix it using 1.3? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177427

This should be fixed in the next release.